# MongoDb Convert Date To String and perform contains operation

Tags: mongodb

What is the equivalent implementation in C# MongoDB for the below SQL query?

```
SELECT person, hiredate
FROM demo 
where CHARINDEX('2019', Convert(varchar,hiredate,105)) > 0
```